# How update a value in the web.config using Octopus?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, octopus-deploy

I need to update a value inside my web.config file during the deployment to true and change it back to false when the deployment is over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options for initially setting the variable during deployment. The **first** is that you could set up a transform file targeting your web.config file (or targeting the web.config directly), then in the transform file, reference an Octopus variable like so `Value="#{valueNameInOctopus}"`.

In Octopus on the variables tab, you'd want to set your variable name and value you want it to have during deployment. Then,  in the 'configure features' section of your process tab, enable the deployment feature to 'Substitute variables in files' and include the name of your transform file or web.config file in the list of target files.

Changing the value back after deployment is a little trickier, since there isn't another built-in transform step, but what you could do is write a post-deployment [powershell script that uses an XML API to do your transforms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61900/PowerShell-and-XML), per the suggestion at the end of [these Octopus docs on configuration](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Configuration+files#Configurationfiles-ConfigurationTransformations). The **second** option for setting the variable's value during deployment is doing it this same way, but as a pre-deployment script. I'd recommend that, for consistency's sake.

I'm not sure why you need the config value to be different during deployment than it is post-deployment, but if it's because there's some unique circumstance on your Octopus server such that you want to do one thing there, but something else on the Tentacles, you might considering setting up a Tentacle on your Octopus server and doing a special deployment to that environment instead.

Comment: I actually will have this setting on DB level so i think i wont be able to fully use your solution. But i still can use the powershell to achieve my goal. I am trying to fix some caching issues..

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Yeah, you can still use the ps script method to toggle the DB value before and after deployment. Good luck!